# How to Deploy Laravel app on Apache Production server

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.5

I am try to run Laravel app in Ubuntu 16.04 Apache server.

It is show server error as fallows

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

but i run it on development artisan server using below command and its working.

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.103 --port=8050
```

pls can you explain what i have done wrong way in Apache server and how to do it correctly.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. Make sure you've run `composer install` to populate the vendor files, and `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: I was run Both command and result is Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

Comment: Hi, any news about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1**

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

**STEP 2**

sudo cp 000-default.conf yourprojectName.conf

**STEP 3**

sudo vi yourprojectName.conf(you should know vi editor command)

**STEP 4**

Update below code

```
        ServerName siteexample.co.in

        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

        <Directory /var/www/project/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

colse the editor

**STEP 5**

sudo a2ensite yourprojectName.conf

**STEP 6**

sudo service apache2 restart

Now will work

Congratulations!